# displaying date in datepicker not showing unless refreshed

Tags: angular, datepicker, angular-material, date-conversion

I have this datepicker function that I've set to set a dynamic date as the default value.

```
<div *ngIf="(user$ | async) as user">
  <div *ngIf="(userPrivate$ | async) as userPrivate">
    <div class="row">
      <p class="col-4">Date of Birth: &nbsp;</p>
      <div *ngIf="!editState || editValue !=  (userPrivate.date_of_birth)" class="col-8">
        <p>{{getDate(userPrivate.date_of_birth)}}
          <i (click)="editUser($event,  userPrivate.date_of_birth)" class="fa fa-pencil mt-2"></i>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div *ngIf="editState && editValue == userPrivate.date_of_birth" class="col-8">
        <form class="row">
          <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker1" [max]="tomorrow" placeholder="Date of Birth" #dob
            [value]="this.userdob">
          <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker1"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
          <mat-datepicker #picker1></mat-datepicker>
          <i (click)="updateUser( user, userPrivate,  dob.value)" class="fa fa-save mt-2 col-3"></i>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

in `[value]="this.userdob"` the date is being converted from unix time to date format

```
var temptdob = this.userService.userdob;
this.userdob = new Date(temptdob * 1 );
```

When I first enter the page, `this.userdob` would be undefined but if i were to toggle out and back to that page then it'll load the date in the input. Why is that so and how can i fix this?

Comment: In which place you are setting the this.userdob  value in your code?

Comment: @Chellappan I've declared userdob in the same file as `userdob: any;`

Comment: Where you are doing this operation (var temptdob = this.userService.userdob;
this.userdob = new Date(temptdob * 1 );  
)

Comment: can you pls share the log value of `this.userService.userdob`

if the date string is not complete with dateTime stamp we've to do
`this.userdob = new Date(this.userService.userdob)`